# Persistance Key store not working kafka streams 2.20

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have an kafka stream application written in scala.

I am creating the persistence key value state stores and adding them to the processor nodes in the application.

I put the values in the state store as key value pair but when I try to access this value with the same key in another processor it gives me null and the method `approximateNumEntries()` give zero.

I do not understand why these values are vanished from the state store.

This happens intermittently, for an instance I restarted my kafka brokers and it started happening again.

I am very new to kafka streams and state stores so any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you maybe share a code snippet (minimum example) how you build your topology and the processor code?

Comment: So finally I was able to find the real issue behind this intermittent behavior. I persistent store was not able to load the data form the partition other than zero. The data which goes to 0th partition was updated successfully in the state store, not rest.